# Perl semicolon at end of statement

Tags: perl

The `;` is used as a statement delimiter, so placing multiple `;` at the end of a statement is fine as it just adds empty statements.

I came across this code which has multiple `;` at the end but deleting them causing errors:

```
$line =~s;[.,]$;;;
```

should be same as

```
$line =~s;[.,;]$;
```

but it is not. What's going on?

Comment: You did more than just remove semicolons in the second statement, you added one in the middle of it.

Comment: [s//: "Any non-whitespace delimiter may replace the slashes."](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2fPATTERN%2fREPLACEMENT%2fmsixpodualgcer)

Comment: Evidently whoever wrote it thought it had high amusement value

Comment: The ; is NOT used as a statement delimiter (like it is in most other languages). The ; in Perl is used as a statement *separator*. This is why the semicolon is optional on the last statement in a block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code only the last `;` is the **statement delimiter**. The others are **regex delimiters** which the substitution operator takes. A better way to write this is:

```
$line =~s/[.,]$//;
```

Since you must have the statement delimiter and regex delimiters in your statement, you can't drop any of the trailing `;`

Answer (score 13):

in the snippet provided by you a `;` is used as a delimiter for a search-n-replace regular expression.

```
$line =~s;[.,]$;;;
```

is equivalent to

```
$line =~ s/[.,]$//;
```

Comment: Just to be clear - yes, it is legal to do. No, you should never ever do that in your code unless you want a raving psychopath to bash your head in. And by raving psychopath I mean the next developer who has to maintain your code.

Answer (score 2):

A semicolon is not universally a statement separator; it can also be a quoted string or regex delimiter.  Or even a variable name, as in this classic JAPH by Abigail, entitled "Things are not what they seem like."

```
$;                              # A lone dollar?
=$";                            # Pod? 
$;                              # The return of the lone dollar?
{Just=>another=>Perl=>Hacker=>} # Bare block?
=$/;                            # More pod?
print%;                         # No right operand for %?
```